# Relação de Tabelas

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, laravel

Criando as minhas *migrations* no Laravel me surgiu a seguinte dúvida:

Tenho estas duas tabelas:

Usados

- ID
- NOME_MARCA_ID
- MODELO
- ANO

MARCAS

- ID
- NOME

na *migration* pra guardar o ID da marca eu faria assim:

```
$table->integer('marca_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('marca_id')->references('id')->on('marcas');
```

Toda informação é guardada através de um formulário. E se eu quiser guardar na tabela `USADOS`, na coluna `NOME_MARCA_ID` o `Nome` e não o `ID` seria possível?

Answer (score 0):

Essa prática, além do Mysql não permitir, não faz muito sentido. Primeiro que para relacionar duas tabelas, o campo de referência precisa ter as suas propriedades idênticas, necessariamente. Segundo, você pode gerar um erro de integridade se em `Marcas` o campo `NOME` puder ser repetido com o mesmo dado em outro registro.

A melhor maneira de fazer é pela chave, que no caso é o `id`, pois assim você conseguirá recuperar todos os outros dados do relacionamento, inclusive o `Nome`, que é o campo em questão.

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

1. De acordo com a 'Integridade de Entidade', não é correto. Deve ser um relacionamento com a chave primário da tabela que será obtido a 'Marca'.
2. Uma query com 'Inner Join' já ajuda a obter o nome da 'Marca'.

   Qualquer dúvida, estamos aí.